# Making browsers remember (for autocomplete) the values of input fields not enclosed within a <form> tag

Tags: html, forms, browser, autocomplete

I have a requirement wherein my page has few `<input>` elements and i want the browser to remember the values typed in them and show the autocomplete drop down for subsequent visits. But the problem is I dont have a `<form>` tag in my page and the processing is done via Javascript/Ajax.

Is there any way i can acheive this?

Comment: Tried adding a `<form>` tag around the elements with a `#` set as the action?

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding a  tag around the elements. Thanks Rory. And also prevented the form submission with attribute `onsubmit="return false;"` on the form tag.

It works on firefox but not in chrome.